# Issue with Special Characters (ñ) in DBF File Generated by PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters, dbase

Description:

I am encountering difficulties when generating a DBF file using PHP's dbase extension. The problem arises when including special characters like "ñ" in the data.

Problem:

The generated DBF file contains ASCII values for special characters instead of the actual characters.
Example: "Jane ñ Doe" becomes "Jane ├▒ Doe" in the DBF file.

I have tried setting the character encoding in PHP using header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');, but the issue persists.
I have attempted to convert special characters to other encodings, but the results are not as expected.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

// Set the DBF file path
$dbfFilePath = 'D:\INCOME\new.dbf';

// Create a DBF file
$dbf = dbase_create($dbfFilePath, [
    ['ID', 'N', 5, 0],
    ['Name', 'C', 50],
]);

// Add sample data with special characters
foreach ([[1, 'John Doe'], [2, 'Jane ñ Doe'], [3, 'Alice']] as $row) {
    dbase_add_record($dbf, $row);
}

// Close the DBF file
dbase_close($dbf);
```

Comment: Please include in your question a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (which you convert the string to a DBF file thru PHP)

Comment: I have updated my question. Do you have any ideas about my problem, sir?

Comment: What do you do with the DBF after it is generated? Do you open it in a legacy app? You must use the same encoding as the app expects (which is obviously not UTF-8). It could be windows-1252, or even an MS-DOS encoding like CP850.

Comment: You can use iconv to convert, e.g. `iconv('UTF-8', 'CP850', 'Jane ñ Doe')`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `iconv()` or `mb_convert_encoding()` in PHP to convert your string encoding from UTF-8 to the required one. For example, if you find that Windows-1252 works, you can use something like the following -->

```
$encodedName = iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252', 'Jane ñ Doe');
```

OR `mb_convert_encoding`

```
$encodedName = mb_convert_encoding('Jane ñ Doe', 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
```

so in the aboce example `'Jane ñ Doe'` (which is in UTF-8) is converted to Windows-1252 encoding. Then use `$encodedName` in your dbase record creation

```
dbase_add_record($dbf, [2, $encodedName]);
```